# Redux thunk: wait for async function to dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm creating a React Native application and using redux and redux-thunk to implement my API requests. I would like to know how I can wait for my action to be dispatched and make sure that my state has been updated in an async thunk logic. If I understand correctly, `await` will wait for the end of the thunk but the action is not dispatched yet. Although, as you can see in my usage, I need the state to be modified to proceed the rest of the code accordingly.

**actions/user.js**

```
export const tryLogin = (
  email: string,
  password: string,
  sessionToken: string = ''
): Function => async (dispatch: Function) => {
  const logUser = () => ({ type: LOG_USER })

  const logUserSuccess = (data: any, infos: any) => ({
    type: LOG_USER_SUCCESS,
    data,
    infos,
  })

  const logUserError = (signinErrorMsg: string) => ({
    type: LOG_USER_ERROR,
    signinErrorMsg,
  })

  dispatch(logUser())

  try {
    { /* Some API requests via axios */ }

    dispatch(logUserSuccess(responseJson, infos))
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    { /* Error handling code */ }

    dispatch(logUserError(error.response.data.error))
    return false
}
```

**reducers/user.js**

```
case LOG_USER:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: true,
  }
case LOG_USER_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: false,
    data: action.data,
    infos: action.infos,
    error: false,
    signinErrorMsg: '',
  }
case LOG_USER_ERROR:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: false,
    error: true,
    signinErrorMsg: action.signinErrorMsg,
  }
```

**RegisterScreen.js**

```
if (await trySignup(
    emailValue,
    firstNameValue,
    lastNameValue,
    passwordValue,
    birthdateValue,
    genderValue
  )
) {
  if (userReducer.data) {
    navigation.navigate('Secured')
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Redux,
When an Action is dispatched to the store, it will update the state of the UI automatically with new props.

Instead of watching the dispatched action, You can add a flag in the reducer `signUpSuccess` similar to `isLoggingIn` flag and listen to the changes in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

`trySignup` can be called separately (like on an event, formSubmit, button click, etc.)

**RegisterScreen.js**

```
class RegisterScreen extends React.Component{
...
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.signUpSuccess !== this.props.signUpSuccess){
    if (this.props.signUpSuccess) {
      navigation.navigate('Secured')
    }
  }
}
...
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  signUpSuccess: state.userReducer.signUpSuccess,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterScreen);
```

Comment: I currently use your approach. BUT I have one big question. Now you save `signUpSuccess` in the store. I have (somewhere) remove this state, if I come back to the login state. How to solve this in a nice way?

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, await will wait for the end of the thunk
>   but the action is not dispatched yet.

- Render can be update if any changes happens in props, so extract props in your render method and update UX as per change in props.
- I would suggest use [React native debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) to check your actions
  and current saved state.